# Load data dynamically into HashMap

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, loaddata

I am reading data from a CSV file and want to store it into hashMap. There are 3 columns, all of them Strings. I am using this code:

```
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.photographers);
    CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(inputStream);
    List<String[]> data = csv.read();
    List<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String[] children : data){
        info.add(children[1]);
        info.add(children[2]);
    }

    //fill data for the child

    for (String[] line : data) {
        listDataHeader.add(line[0]);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),info);
    }
```

The listdataChild should keep the info of the 2nd and 3rd column in the CSV. Currently, it's loading the that info more than once. I'd welcome any ideas, thank you!

Comment: Your question is not very clear, in your CSV  the first column is your header ? and you want to keep 2 and 3rd columns in the map as values and first column as key in the map?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The first column keeps the info that needs to go in the listDataHeader (key), whereas the next two function as values and need to be stored in listdataChild. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with just one iteration.

```
for (String[] line : data) {
    List<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
    info.add(line[1]);
    info.add(line[2]);
    listDataChild.put(line[0], info);
}
```

Here, you are iterating through the rows of your csv and creating a **new** list and adding your second and third columns to that list and adding that list to the map.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But where should I say that info stores the information from columns 2 and 3?